# Arduino: need assistance in understanding <keyboard.h> library

Tags: keyboard, arduino, usb, hid

I have Leonardo/Micro device that should emulate Keyboard. 
I would like to modify  library. The reason is I would like to be able to send raw scancodes, wheras the library does some preparation.
I looked in the source code, also of HID library, dbut have difficulty to understand following points:

1. Keyboard_::begin() and Keyboard_::end() are supposed to [start](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/KeyboardBegin) and [stop](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/KeyboardEnd) keboard emulation, but they have empty bodies; https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/KeyboardBegin
2. KeyReport is especially mysterious:
3. What exactly happens to the keyreport? I lost track in USB_Send function in HID.cpp. Couldnt find where it comes from
4. What are modifiers, what they ar4 doing?
5. Is number of keys sent limited to 6 or, theoretically could be be arbitrary?

Comment: [Knock yourself out.](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions the best I can. Let me know if you still have questions:

> 1. Keyboard_::begin() and Keyboard_::end() are supposed to start and stop keboard emulation, but they have empty bodies

I believe those are just placeholders in case any initialization or cleanup would need to be done. The other libraries have the same functions (e.g. the Mouse library). I suspect they are there for consistency and just in case they are needed.

> 2. KeyReport is especially mysterious.

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t modifiers;
    uint8_t reserved;
    uint8_t keys[6];
} KeyReport;
```

KeyReport is the data structure that represents the USB message sent to the host computer.

- The modifiers member is an 8-bit unsigned integer that contains various flags (e.g. Left Shift, Left Ctrl, Left Alt, etc.)
- The reserved member is an 8-bit unsigned integer that is not used, but must be there.
- The keys member is an array of six 8-bit unsigned integers that represent the keys that are currently pressed.

> 3. What exactly happens to the keyreport? I lost track in USB_Send function in HID.cpp.

It gets sent to the host computer.

> 4. What are modifiers, what they are doing?

Some keys are “regular” keys (e.g. A, B, 1, 2, #, etc.). Other keys are modifiers (e.g. Shift, Ctrl, Alt). The modifier keys set flags in KeyReport.modifiers. For example, the Left Shift key is 0x02.

> 5. Is number of keys sent limited to 1 or, theoretically could be arbitrary?

The number of “regular” keys that can be press simultaneously is 6, but you could also have the modifier keys pressed (Shift, Alt, Ctrl, etc.).

FYI: I have been able to add additional keys (e.g. the numeric keypad keys) by adding new key definitions to the USBAPI.h file:

```
#define KEY_NUMPAD_DIVIDE   0xDC
#define KEY_NUMPAD_MULTIPLY 0xDD
#define KEY_NUMPAD_MINUS    0xDE
#define KEY_NUMPAD_PLUS     0xDF
#define KEY_NUMPAD_ENTER    0xE0
#define KEY_NUMPAD_1        0xE1
#define KEY_NUMPAD_2        0xE2
#define KEY_NUMPAD_3        0xE3
#define KEY_NUMPAD_4        0xE4
#define KEY_NUMPAD_5        0xE5
#define KEY_NUMPAD_6        0xE6
#define KEY_NUMPAD_7        0xE7
#define KEY_NUMPAD_8        0xE8
#define KEY_NUMPAD_9        0xE9
#define KEY_NUMPAD_0        0xEA
#define KEY_NUMPAD_DEL      0xEB
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I do have need for further clarification.  I post them in comments below

Comment: 1. First of all you are right:  I tested and begin() and end() have unsurprisingly no effect,  despite Arduino guide heavily implies otherwise. But may be that's what they should do in my version of the keyboard: taking and giving back control of the keyboard? How would it be possible?

Comment: 2. Do I understand correctly  that CTRL, ALT  cant be sent as keys, but instead are used as modifiers?

Comment: 3 Where can I find bitmasks for the modifiers?

Comment: 4. I realize I made a mistake that led to some misunderstanding. I meant to ask  can I create my own KeyReport struct with lets say 20 keys?

Comment: 1. If you are writing your own keyboard library, I do not think you need to do anything in the begin() or end() methods.

Comment: > 2. Do I understand correctly that CTRL, ALT cant be sent as keys, but instead are used as modifiers?  -Correct. CTRL, ATL, SHIFT, etc. are modifier keys. They are "pressed" via the modifiers member.

Comment: > 3 Where can I find bitmasks for the modifiers?
They are defined in the Keyboard.h file (in Arduino IDE Version 1.6.6 and above). To get the actual mask value you need to subtract 0x7F (127). For example KEY_LEFT_CTRL is defined as 0x80, so its modifier mask is 0x01, KEY_LEFT_SHIFT is defined as 0x81, so its modifier mask is 0x02, etc.

Comment: > 4.  I meant to ask can I create my own KeyReport struct with lets say 20 keys? I think it is possible. You will need to update the _hidReportDescriptor defined in to the Keyboard.cpp file, but I am not 100% sure what needs to be changed. I know you will need to update the REPORT_SIZE to include the new characters, but there is probably some other things you need to do as well. There may be a limit to the number of keys pressed the host computer supports as well. Also, almost all of the USB Keyboard Report Descriptors I have seen only support 6 characters (or less).

Comment: Last points before I gratefully accept the answer: 1 So I omit them entirely 2. but what about scancodes 0x1d, 0x2a, 0x36 etc that present those modifier keys? 4 . what happens if I send 2 reports without clearing the keys, ie I send a Keyreport with scancodes of 'qwerty' and then a Keyreport with scancodes of 'asdfgh'. Will it override the previous one or add new keys as pressed?

Comment: Scan code 0x1d (LEFT CTRL) needs to be mapped to modifier 0x01 (it is not sent as a "keys" value), 0x2a (LEFT SHIFT) needs to be mapped to modifier 0x02, etc. With regards to the "what happens if I send 2 reports without clearing the keys" question, I am not sure, but I think the host computer will assume the first set of keys was released and the second set was pressed (but I am not 100% sure one this). You will have to try it out and let us know.